# PHP & AJAX: How to produce a heat map based on number values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to something new that I've never done before. I searched everywhere online and couldn't find any tutorials.

[here is my fiddle for better understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/jbke9un2/)Each of those squares are DIVS.
The number inside of is being retrieved with an AJAX call that GETs it with a PHP script executing 
a query.

**Problem:**

How can I produce a "heat map" based on the numbers being displayed.
Example: Lets say the number range is from 100(the lowest) to 1800(the highest).
Depending on the number range, a background color will have to be displayed from
green-ish, to yellow-ish, orange-ish, red..and so on.

**AJAX:how I am displaying the numbers inside of the DIVs**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{  } , // do I need to pass data if im GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                            var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                            if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
```

THIS IS WHERE I AM OUTPUTTING THE NUMBER

```
      divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']); // set inner HTML with AHT value


                            }//end if
                            }//end for
                      }//end success
                });//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

**PHP numbers being retrieved from**

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
    // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) 
    $userdata = $user[$username];
    //if AHT is null give N/A as value
    if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => 'NA',
                                             'station'  => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end inner if 
    //else give the actual value of AHT without the decimals
    else {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => substr($memodata['aht_value'],0,-3),
                                             'station'   => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end else
    }//end outer if
    }//end for

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Try: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/

Comment: Has too many files for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using HSL colors, here's a function I end up using fairly often for a quick heatmap gen. Get your input into the range of [0,1] first.

```
// value [0,1]
function heatmap_color_for(value) {
  var h = (1 - value) * 100;
  var s = 100;
  var l = value * 50;

  return 'hsl('+h.toFixed(2)+', '+s.toFixed(2)+'%, '+l.toFixed(2)+'%)';
}
```

Demo:

```js
  // value [0,1]
  function heatmap_color_for(value) {
    var h = (1 - value) * 100;
    var s = 100;
    var l = value * 50;
    
    return 'hsl('+h.toFixed(2)+', '+s.toFixed(2)+'%, '+l.toFixed(2)+'%)';
  }

  $('div').each(function (i,item) {
    $(this).css('background-color', heatmap_color_for(Math.random()))
  })
```

```css
div {
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        float:left;
        margin:3px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: sorry if this might be a silly question but how do I replace the "value" with  **data[i]['aht_value']** Do I include the function you provided into mine or how do I make the relation? Thanks

Comment: Include the function. As I said, you need to normalize the input into a number in the range of [0,1], which supposes you have a max. Then: `var scaledNum = rawInput / max`